# MYSQL #1064 error unable to find cause

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query on mysql ran from XAMPP

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS htmlProject;
CREATE SCHEMA htmlProject;
USE htmlProject;

--
-- Table structure for table `actor`
--
CREATE TABLE ACTORS (
  actor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  actor_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  joined_on DATETIME NOT NULL,
  actor_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (actor_id),
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE TAGS (
  tag_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tag_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (tag_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE FILES (
  files_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  files_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  uploaded_on DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (files_id),
  actor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  KEY idx_fk_actor_id (actor_id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_files_actors` FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES ACTORS(actor_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE FILESTAG (
  files_tag_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  tag_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  files_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (files_tag_id)
  KEY idx_fk_tag_id (tag_id),
  KEY idx_fk_files_id (files_id),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_files_tags` FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES TAGS (tag_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tags_files` FOREIGN KEY (files_id) REFERENCES FILES (files_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

But still I am getting an error 1064 on the following lines

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 27 in file: 'C:\Users\hanyd\Desktop\HTML project\html_project_query2.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 7
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 53 in file: 'C:\Users\hanyd\Desktop\HTML project\html_project_query2.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(files_tag_id),
  KEY idx_fk_tag_id (tag_id),
  KEY idx_fk_files_id (files_id),
' at line 5
```

I absolutely have no idea why this is happening, even though I have written similar queries before with absolutely no error of this kind. What is slipping my attention here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma:

```
CREATE TABLE FILESTAG (
 files_tag_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 tag_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 files_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL   <---- Add comma here
```

And you have a comma where there shouldn't be one:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTORS (
  actor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  actor_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  joined_on DATETIME NOT NULL,
  actor_password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (actor_id),             <--- REMOVE this comma
  )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Okay okay i'll recheck syntax

Comment: This seems to be the error, I have several still unchecked syntax errors, terribly sorry for wasting your time, it seems my senses aren't really at their best tonight. Thank you